# CakePHP + Oracle + CamelCased column table names issue

Tags: oracle, cakephp, names, camelcasing

We are working on a huge project using Cakephp. We've started using MySQL, but now they are asking to move to Oracle! Now, we've just start this lovely task! :)

We are **not** using cakephp patterns, but camel cased names for tables and its columns (It was a client requirement!).

Columns table names in Oracle are Case Sensitive as we put the name between "" (double quotes) when creating tables. If we don't, Oracle put uppercased.

But cakephp's oracle drive seems to ignore camelcased configuration, parse field name always as case insensitive and turns names into lowercased at the query result array.

Instead of

```
$res['TableName']['ColumnName']  //camelcased
```

I got

```
$res['TableName']['columnname']  //lowercased! :(
```

Does anybody have any idea how to overcome it?

Comment: Column names in oracle dbms **are** case sensitive. And if you don't specify it explicitly in double quotes - all names are upper-cased.

Comment: You're right, zerkms! I've updated the question.

Comment: Update:
Change CamelCase notation was not an option.
For now, we did the following:
- Improvements in the CakePHP driver for Oracle (we can post later!)
- Created a script to map the name of the tables (eg idperson => IdPerson). It's probably not the best approach,. At least, we will use the query cache. ;)

In addition, we are facing a lot of issues caused by differences between MySQL and Oracle, their drivers in CakePHP. 

We already know the "just changing driver" is pure illusion. But still had some unexpected issues. This would be a nice paper.

I'll keep you all posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have a hard talk with your client. If camel casing is a client requirement then they shouldn't use Oracle. You can't have both, it will be one hacked mess, since everything in Oracle gets upper cased, tables, columns, stored procs and the list goes on.

You will end up hacking everything with "Table1"."Column1" quotes. This will not be highly maintainable and every Oracle DBA will need to context switch when they look at the database structures.

They, your client, either need go with the Oracle standards or not use Oracle.

Comment: Yes, Marthinus! We've started this talk, then I realize that would be wise get good arguments.

And we also learned about this quotes behavior, but the point is: "Is it really a good way to re-code / modify CakePHP Oracle Drive"? We don't think so, since we are against the Oracle standards, like you said.

Comment: Personally I hate it when a customer starts prescribing technology. You have experts in many fields, so if you can't trust your chosen experts in their field, which in this case is the chosen software development vendor, then the relationship is not off to a good start at all.

Our company usually just don't entertain such behaviour at all, we just put it down in plain English, either you trust us and our track record, or we don't do business.

Comment: We're still dealing with this. Once we decide the final solution, I'll share here.